# Concatenate HTML element with HTML string for Leaflet's bindPopup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet

I am trying to write a functionality for editing feature attributes through `layer.bindPopup` for Leaflet features. At this point I have pretty much everything I need, except of the one last thing: [Documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#multipolyline) is saying that `layer.bindPopup` takes either HTML string or HTML element, so I need to concatenate my `HTMLString` with two elements: `saveChanges` button and `speed_input` input and then feed `layer.bindPopup` with it. Any manipulations with `$.append` did not help. Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

```
function onEachArc(feature, layer) {
            // Create an input
            var speed_input = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'speed');

            // Set a feature property as value
            speed_input.value = feature.properties.speed;

            // Add a listener to watch for change on time input
            L.DomEvent.addListener(speed_input, 'change', function(){
                // Change the value of speed
                feature.properties.speed = speed_input.value;
            });

            // Bind popup to layer with input
            HTMLString = '<table style="width:100%">\
                <tr style="background-color:grey">\
                <th><b>Arc Numer: </b>' + feature.properties.linkstr + '</br></th>\
                </tr>\
                <tr>\
                <td><b>Speed: </b> ' + feature.properties.speed + '.</div></td>\
                </tr>\
                </table>';

            var saveChanges = document.createElement('button');
            saveChanges.innerHTML = 'Save Changes';
            saveChanges.onclick = function(){
                $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"php/updateFeature.php",
                        data: {feature: feature},
                        success: function(data){
                                $('#test').html(data);
                            }
                    });
                    //return false;
                    }
                };   

                /*
                This did not help
                var box =  document.createElement("div");
                    box.style.width = "100px";
                    box.style.height = "100px";
                $("#box").append("#saveChanges");
                layer.bindPopup(box);
                */

                layer.bindPopup(saveChanges);
            };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use innerHTML:

> The Element.innerHTML property sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants.

```
var form = L.DomUtil.create('form', 'my-form');

form.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="my-input" />';

var button = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'my-button', form);
button.textContent = 'Ok!';
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/DiK1zj?p=info

or use outerHTML:

> On return, content contains the serialized HTML fragment describing the element and its descendants.

```
var inputHTML = '<input type="text" class="my-input" />';

var button = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'my-button', form);
button.textContent = 'Ok!';

var buttonHTML = button.outerHTML;

var form = '<form class="my-form">' + inputHTML + buttonHTML + '</form>';
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z6rADJ?p=preview

That said (and after reading your comment), i must say: this works but is very hacky. I wouldn't recommend doing this sort of thing this way. You either build your form with HTML elements or use a template/string and convert that into HTML elements so you can attach handlers and process stuff. Mixing things up will get you into trouble. I would approach it this way:

The template:

```
var template = '<form id="popup-form">\
  <label for="input-speed">New speed:</label>\
  <input id="input-speed" class="popup-input" type="number" />\
  <table class="popup-table">\
    <tr class="popup-table-row">\
      <th class="popup-table-header">Arc numer:</th>\
      <td id="value-arc" class="popup-table-data"></td>\
    </tr>\
    <tr class="popup-table-row">\
      <th class="popup-table-header">Current speed:</th>\
      <td id="value-speed" class="popup-table-data"></td>\
    </tr>\
  </table>\
  <button id="button-submit" type="button">Save Changes</button>\
</form>';
```

Use a stylesheet, keeps the template nice and clean:

```
.popup-table {
  width: 100%;
}

.popup-table-row {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

In the `onEachFeature` function, attach a click handler:

```
L.geoJson(collection, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', layerClickHandler);
  }
});
```

And handle it:

```
function layerClickHandler (e) {

  var marker = e.target,
      properties = e.target.feature.properties;

  // Check if a popup was previously set if so, unbind  
  if (marker.hasOwnProperty('_popup')) {
    marker.unbindPopup();
  }

  // Create new popup from template and open it
  marker.bindPopup(template);
  marker.openPopup();

  // Now that the popup is open and the template converted to HTML and
  // attached to the DOM you can query for elements by their ID

  L.DomUtil.get('value-arc').textContent = properties.arc;
  L.DomUtil.get('value-speed').textContent = properties.speed;

  var inputSpeed = L.DomUtil.get('input-speed');
  inputSpeed.value = properties.speed;
  L.DomEvent.addListener(inputSpeed, 'change', function (e) {
    properties.speed = e.target.value;
  });

  var buttonSubmit = L.DomUtil.get('button-submit');
  L.DomEvent.addListener(buttonSubmit, 'click', function (e) {
    // Do fancy ajax stuff then close popup
    marker.closePopup();
  });

}
```

Example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8qVoW5?p=preview

This is cleaner, faster, it doesn't bind popups to every marker. It's more readable, extendable and less error prone. I hope that help, good luck!

Comment: I would prefer outerHTML method better, because I feel that it's easier to operate with HTML string eventually. But if I add `onclick` event on this button, it would not work:
     `button.onclick = function(e){ e.preventDefault(); alert("hi")}`

Comment: It's hacky but i'm just answering your question, this isn't a very clean way to do this sort of thing. I'll elaborate a little more in my answer.

Comment: Wow! This is really fancy! I was checking out [this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/clicks-in-popups/) example and I understood the reason why my previous approach did not work - the HTML I put in bindPopup doesn't exist yet, like it is explained in the example. But l couldn't think of the way to create HTML first and then access it from the `layer.on('click')` function. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes, when you use a string popup content you can only query it's elements and attach handlers after it has been attached to the DOM. But you can attach an eventhandler to a HTMLelement which you've created and has not been attached to the DOM. Doing `var button = L.DomUtil.create('button', 'my-button')` and then L.DomEvent.addListener(button, 'click', function(){})` works perfectly fine once you add it to the DOM. But when you turn it in to an string like in my first example: `var buttonHTML = button.outerHTML` the listener gets destroyed.